# Can feature in machine-learning be matrix?

Tags: machine-learning

As you know, the feature in Iris dataset is 1 dimensional array for example :

```
[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2]  Iris-Setosa  
[7.0, 3.2, 4.7, 1.4]  Iris-versicolor
```

I'm wondering if feature in machine-learning can be 2d-arrays or not ?
For example:

```
Feature                            Result  
[[1.0  2.3  3.1],[2.4  6.3  9.6]]  A  
[[1.5  3.3  5.1],[5.4  9.3  7.0]]  B
```

Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they can be. In this case, the input become [Tensors](https://machinelearningblogs.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Screen-Shot-2017-06-26-at-4.00.33-PM.png).

0 dimensional input - scalars

1 dimensional input - vectors

2 dimensional input - matrices

3 (and above) dimensional input - tensors

An image for example is a (m x n x p) tensor with RGB components. So each input is a multi-dimensional array of numbers. It is a matrix of matrices - [This is an excellent explanation](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/)

Word embeddings are also somewhat similar. Words make up a document. A corpus is a collection of documents. In this case each word is typically 1 300-number vector. So a document will be a matrix - so each input is a matrix - [Start here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding)