# How can I use a matrix with variable length as a feature in a structured dataset as input to train an AI model using Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have a dataset associated with real-world physical structures. Each row of this dataset describes properties (represented by a single numeric or categorical value), damage occurrences (represented by a matrix [m, 3] containing two characteristics of the damage and its extent), and needed repairs (represented also by a matrix [n, 2] containing the type of repair and its associated quantity). A basic representation of the dataset is shown below.

Explaining briefly, the needed repairs are primarily associated with the damage occurrences and some specific properties of the physical structure. However, I expect to evaluate the influence of all the available parameters in the repairs matrix. The main objective of the model I'm looking forward to is to predict the set of repairs and repair quantities based on properties and damage instances of new structures.

| Index | Structure Type | Lenght | Width | ... | Damages instances | Repairs (outputs) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | type_1 | 12.2 | 13.0 | ... | [[damage1, damaged_element1, 2.5], [damage2, damaged_element1, 0.8], [damage1, damaged_element2, 1.1], ...] | [[repair1, 21.4], [repair2, 8.0], [repair3, 12.4], [repair4, 5.5] ...] |
| 2 | type_2 | 8.0 | 12.0 | ... | [[damage2, damaged_element1, 1.1], [damage2, damaged_element1, 4.7], [damage3, damaged_element1, 5.2], ...] | [[repair2, 11.0], [repair3, 41.0], [repair5, 23.5], [repair6, 1.0] ...] |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| n | type_1 | 24.0 | 13.5 | ... | [[damage4, damaged_element3, 3.4], [damage1, damaged_element2, 0.8], [damage4, damaged_element1, 3.2], ...] | [[repair1, 20.0], [repair3, 5.2], [repair4, 11.7], [repair5, 4.6] ...] |

Some important particularities to be considered before encoding the data are:

- The "damages instances" matrix can contain more than one instance from the same category, given by the combination between the damage type and the damaged element, and each instance matters (since its extents will be taken into account estimate the quantities of the associated repairs);
- The "repairs" matrix will have only one instance of each repair type;
- Repairs are mostly directly associated with damage types, varying according to the damaged element;
- The number of rows of the "damages instances" and "repairs" matrix will change from each entry of the dataset, and their length in each dana entry will most likely be different (m != n).

Based on the premises described, I found few references of similar problems in which one sought to use complete matrices as features. These references can be found at [Can feature in machine-learning be matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248585/can-feature-in-machine-learning-be-matrix) and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73360/use-matrix-feature-for-machine-learning-or-cluster-analysis. One of the approaches indicated was creating a CNN, which I tried without success.

I'm thinking that an alternative could be:

- Separate each column in the input and output matrices ("Damages instances" and "Repairs");
- Use `sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder()` to encode the categorical data;
- Concatenate the information from each column in a single vector using `np.concatenate()`;
- Create an input layer for each column from the input matrix with `shape = (None)` (since the length is variable);
- Link the input layers from the matrix to the Embedding layers;
- Concatenate the output from the three Embedding layers with the other features and complete the model.

However, I'm not sure if using an Embedding layer will keep track of multiple instances from the same category combination present in the "Damages instances" matrix, which would influence the output.

Then, I would therefore like to ask for some guidance on this problem. I could have good results using a CNN and the raw matrix as an input, or the alternative approach is more interesting?